# Skip next n breakpoints in lldb

Tags: python, xcode, lldb

In gdb I could skip next n breakpoints by "continue n", or skip next n lines by "next n". What's the equivalents in lldb?

And if there was none, how could I create them myself in lldb python extension? I tried something like this, but it didn't work, lldb hangs when I type the command I added.

```
def cc(debugger, args, result, dict):
    target = debugger.GetSelectedTarget()
    process = target.GetProcess()
    process.Continue()
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `process continue` command accepts a `-i` option which will ignore the next *i* matches for the breakpoint you're currently stopped at on the current thread.  e.g.

```
Process 13559 stopped
* thread #1: tid = 0xb7da5, 0x0000000100000f21 a.out`main + 49 at a.c:7, stop reason = breakpoint 2.1
    #0: 0x0000000100000f21 a.out`main + 49 at a.c:7
   4        int i;
   5        for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
   6        {
-> 7            printf ("%d\n", i);
   8        }
   9    }
(lldb) c -i 5
Process 13559 resuming
0
1
2
3
4
5
Process 13559 stopped
* thread #1: tid = 0xb7da5, 0x0000000100000f21 a.out`main + 49 at a.c:7, stop reason = breakpoint 2.1
    #0: 0x0000000100000f21 a.out`main + 49 at a.c:7
   4        int i;
   5        for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
   6        {
-> 7            printf ("%d\n", i);
   8        }
   9    }
(lldb)
```

You can also set the ignore-count of a breakpoint directly with `breakpoint modify -i count bpnum`.

Comment: One more thing. What about skip next n lines?(like `next n` in gdb). In lldb,`process` does not have `step-over` sub-command. `thread` do have `step-over`, but looks like it does not take `-i` option.

Comment: Having `thread step-over` (aka `n`) take a `-i` option would be a good enhancement, I'll suggest it.  You can add a temporary breakpoint (a "one-shot" breakpoint) with the command alias `tbr` (it's just an option to `breakpoint set`) although I can't remember when `tbr` was added to lldb - might not be in a released version yet.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work when the debugger stops on things that aren't breakpoints.